# OpenGL Shadow mapping. Performing calculations on the GPU?

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk, shadow-mapping

I'm using a simple attenuation algorithm to darken walls based on their distance from light sources.

[image]

The end goal is to develop a light-mapping system in which the brightness for each wall is calculated in a pre-pass (including shadowing from other walls), and then that light-map image is blended with the wall texture.

[image] + [image] = [image]

Besides shadowing, I have the light-maps working, and the result replicate the shader code exactly. The problem is it is slow, and adding raycasted shadow checking is only going to make it worse.

My question is this, how can I perform these calculations on the GPU? Is a third party library/module required, or can it be done natively through OpenGL (OpenTK in my case)?

Alternatively, I'd be happy to switch to deferred rendering/lighting with cube shadow mapping but I'm yet to come across any information I can get my head around.

**c# lightmap** (run once for each wall)

```
public void createLightMap()
{
    // Determine Light Map dimensions
    int LightMapSize = 300; 
    int w = (int)(this.Width * LightMapSize);
    int h = (int)(this.Height * LightMapSize);

    // Create Bitmap
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(w, h);

    // Fragment testing
    Vector3 fragmentPosition = new Vector3(this.x2, this.Height, this.z2);
    float xIncement = (1f / LightMapSize) * ((x2 - x) / this.Width);
    float zIncement = (1f / LightMapSize) * ((z2 - z) / this.Width);
    float yIncement = (1f / LightMapSize);


    // Calculate Light value for each pixel
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            // Update fragment position
            fragmentPosition.X = this.x2 -  xIncement -(xIncement * x);
            fragmentPosition.Z = this.z2 - (zIncement * x);
            fragmentPosition.Y = this.Height - (yIncement * y);

            Vector3 totalDiffuse = Vector3.Zero;

            // Iterate through the lights
            for (int n = 0; n < 2; n++)
            {
                Light light = Game.lights[n];
                Vector3 LightPosition = new Vector3(light.Position);
                Vector3 Attenuation = new Vector3(light.Attenuation);
                Vector3 Colour = new Vector3(light.Colour);
                Vector3 toLightVector = LightPosition - fragmentPosition;

                // Return early if wall is facing away from light
                if (Vector3.Dot(this.normalVector, toLightVector.Normalized()) < 0)
                    continue;

                // Calculate vector length (aka, distance from lightsource)
                float distance = (float)Math.Sqrt(toLightVector.X * toLightVector.X + toLightVector.Y * toLightVector.Y + toLightVector.Z * toLightVector.Z);

                // Attenuation
                float attFactor = Attenuation.X + (Attenuation.Y * distance) + (Attenuation.Z * distance * distance);
                Vector3 diffuse = Colour / attFactor;
                totalDiffuse += diffuse;
            }
            // Create bitmap
            var r = (int)(totalDiffuse.X * 256);
            var g = (int)(totalDiffuse.Y * 256);
            var b = (int)(totalDiffuse.Z * 256);

            r = Math.Min(r, 255);
            g = Math.Min(g, 255);
            b = Math.Min(b, 255);

            // Set Pixel
            bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
        }
    }
    this.LightMapTextureID = Texture.loadImage(bitmap);
}
```

**Fragment shader** (an alternative to above light-mapping, creating the same effect)

```
#version 330

precision highp float;

in vec2 frag_texcoord;
in vec3 toLightVector[8];

uniform sampler2D MyTexture0;
uniform vec3 LightColour[8];
uniform vec3 LightAttenuation[8];

uniform float NumberOfLights;

out vec4 finalColor;

void main(void)
{
    vec3 totalDiffuse;

    for (int i=0; i<NumberOfLights; i++) {
    {
        float distance = length(toLightVector[i]);
        float attFactor = LightAttenuation[i].x + (LightAttenuation[i].y * distance) + (LightAttenuation[i].z * distance * distance);
        vec3 diffuse = (LightColour[i]) / attFactor;
        totalDiffuse += diffuse;
    }
    finalColor = vec4(totalDiffuse, 1.0) * texture(MyTexture0, frag_texcoord)
    }
}
```

Comment: For complex lighting, deferred rendering will speed up algorithms by making computation only on rendered pixels. For differed rendering, your first pass will output to multiple frame buffer attachments all the required info's for further computation, then the second pass retrieve info from frame buffer textures. (Multisampling has to be enabled for good results)

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept, and I think you're right, it's the way to go. At this point I'm working on shadow cube maps, which I will either bake to textures in a pre-pass, or balls-to-wall it with deferred rendering. This is all pretty new stuff to me so it takes a lot of time to get things working. I want to start work on the game already!